# How to factor in undecided voters to winning chances?

Tags: statistics

If a 300 people well-conducted poll say:

- 35% Candidate A
- 5% Candidate B
- 60% Undecided

Can something be said about the winning chances of Candidate A?
Is there a way to factor in the undecided statistically?

Comment: As a general matter, you need to make some assumption regarding how "Undecideds" will likely vote.    In this case, even if you assume that every undecided will go for $B$, $A$ still wins so $A$ looks safe here,  But this is an extreme example.

Comment: You are right, it is an easy example. I changed the numbers a bit. I am wondering whether there is a statistical formula that determines the winning chances given a certain undecided percentage.

Comment: Not without further assumptions, no.  I mean...you can look at how "undecideds" have voted as a function of how the decideds have committed and model the next election on that...but there are many risky assumptions in that.

Answer (score 0):

As long as there's no reason to assume that the 'undecided' group will show a different behaviour in the future, you could divide the votes in Undecided pro rata between options A and B. The estimated totals would then be:

- A: 35% + (60% x 35/40) = 87.5%
- B: 5% + (60% x 5/40) = 12.5%
- Undecided: 0, total 100%

Note that this is a very naive, numbers-only approach. If, for example, this poll was done before an election, and between the poll and the election one of the candidates rescues a three-legged puppy from a burning building, your mileage may vary.